# Only display content if loaded from within a frame from specific domains?

Tags: php, html, session, iframe, referer

Most questions regarding frame detection seem to be from people wanting to prevent their website appearing inside a frame. However, I am trying to find a way of denying a particular php page from displaying unless it is in a frame . One caveat is that the iframe and main page are on different domains.

domain1.com/index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Site/title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="http://domain2.com/browse.php" />   
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried the following as a way of verification:

- Looking at the REFERER information in domain2.com/browse.php to see if it has been referred from domain1.com/index.php. This had limited success as I recorded around 1,000 visitors a day that had referer information disabled
- Passing the IP address of the user from domain1.com/index.php to domain2.com/browse.php as part of an encrypted querystring. This also had limited success, but I think that caching (despite my attempts to disable it) was causing index.php to pass an old encrypted querystring to browse.php with an outdated IP address.

**Ideally I'd like to know if domain2.com/browse.php was loaded within domain1.com/index.php, but if this is not possible, I'd like browse.php not to display content if it is not in an iframe.**

Help much appreciated

Comment: just how secure does this need to be?

Comment: Not very as i want browse.php to deliver different content if it is not iframed, hiding he fact that they have essentially been denied direct access to browse.php

Answer (score 0):

You've used the PHP tag in your question. Why not use PHP to include the external page:

```
<?php

// get doc from url
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadhtmlfile('http://bitinfocharts.com/x11coin/');

function getElements($tagName,$stripTag = FALSE)
// echo all these elements in direct succession
{
  global $doc;
  $elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName($tagName);
  foreach ($elements as $node)
  {
    $html = $doc->savehtml($node);
    if ($stripTag)
    {
      $html = substr($html,strpos($html,'>')+1);
      $html = substr($html,0,strrpos($html,'<'));
    }
    echo $html;
  }
}

?><!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
    <head>
        <title>Site</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
        <?php echo '        <base href="'.$url.'">'.PHP_EOL; ?>
        <?php echo '        '; getElements('link'); ?>
        <?php echo '        '; getElements('script'); ?>
        <?php echo '        '; getElements('style'); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
           <?php getElements('body',TRUE); ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not saying this is perfect, nor do I know this is what you want, but it hides the external source well. Password protect it, and nobody can load it.

You insist on using an `<iframe>`. What you could do is retrieve the external file with a simple local php file with, you guessed it, `file_get_contents()`, and echo it. All you need to add to the content is again the `<base>` tag. What does this help? Two points:

1. You now can restrict downloading from your external server to only the server you want to allow to download it.
2. That server happens to be the server where your `<iframe>` page is. You can check on that server, before you serve the content of the `<iframe>` that they've just downloaded the `<iframe>` page.

So you don't need any communication between servers to validate the download. Do make sure the `<iframe>` page is not cached!

(sorry about so many edits, but this editor is a bit weird.)

Comment: As much as i'd like to do that, the content in the iframed page needs to stay in an iframe as javascript on it checks to make sure it is being run from domain2.com. Would I be right in saying that the method above would be quite similar to a `$content = file_get_contents('http://domain2.com/browse.php')` minus the inclusion of the base href?

Comment: No it's not quite the same as `file_get_contents()`. I strip out all the bits that are already present in your page (<head>,<body>,etc) and include all the needed bits like <style> and <script>. No it's definately not the same. I just thought of another solution, new answer.

Comment: Ah yes sorry I see that now. Very handy code, but will await your other solution to see if it meets my 'run from domain2.com' requirement.

Comment: Have just seen your edit. I cant quite get my head around how this would work? The content on domain2.com is 'aware' of where it is being run from (basically its JS ads and stats scripts) and needs to still run from domain2.com. By echo'ing it from file_get_contents() - even with the <base> header, would this not fail the validation ?

Comment: Ah, yes, that would be a problem. If you want to keep the file on domain2.com, and still use timestamps, as explained in my second answer, you could let it ask the time from domain1.com. just put a file on it with this very short script: `<?php echo time(); ?>`. You have to do this because you can never be sure that the clocks are in sync.

Answer (score 0):

So, my idea is to download the external page locally. Let's call this local page 'LOCAL'. And let's call the page it will be loaded into, in an '` 'IFRAME'.

You restrict downloading of your external page to the server where LOCAL is located.

The simplest way to verify that a user is authorized to see LOCAL is by using encoded timestamps. So when IFRAME is generated by the server, it simply puts an encoded timestamp on the URL of LOCAL. Why encoded? Because it shouldn't be too obvious what it is, and you need to be able to decode it in LOCAL.

So first the way to generate the encode timestamp:

```
$code = urlencode(gzencode(time()));
```

In LOCAL we will use the opposite:

```
$timestamp = gzdecode(urldecode($code)));
```

Please test these routines, `urldecode()` might already have been applied on your server. You can make these encoding en decoding routines more complex if you want to make it harder for hackers to guess what's going on.

Now in your LOCAL file you first need to check that the timestamp you got is indeed a number and not too old:

```
if (is_numeric($timestamp)) $age = abs(time()-$timestamp); 
                       else $age = 99999999;
```

You could serve an empty page if the content is older than 5 minutes, for instance. Don't forget to set the `<base>` tag in LOCAL, you could use the DOM classes for that, just like in my previous answer. Alternatively you could make all relative links absolute.

There's one clear drawback to this idea. There might be javascripts that rely on the fact that they run on the external server. In this case they don't, and that might break them.

(Why do I make so many typo's?)